# Quickly switch database-first EF to map a different table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework (v6.2.0 currently) in a .NET Framework project and I have many database tables mapped with an edmx project. This all works fine (most of the time).

What I would like to be able to do, however, is take an entity, let's call it `Foo` which is mapped to the `Foo` table in the database and be able to switch that mapping instead to a copy of that table in the database, let's call it `Foo2` without having to import `Foo2` into EF and have it create a `Foo2` entity that I will then need to change every reference to `Foo` to `Foo2`.

I'm not sure if there is an easy way to do this. Ideally I would like something like this somewhere in the code (maybe in `MyDatabaseEntities` partial class derived from `DbContext`?):

```
#if USETHEOTHERTABLE
   map Foo entities to the Foo2 table
#else
   map Foo entities to the Foo table
#endif
```

And obviously not have all this get screwed up the next time EF does regenerates the code.

I thinking that `OnModelCreating` in the entity class would be the place to do this, but EF has already generated one in `MyDatabaseEntities` like this:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
```

Which feels like a) a warning not to do this. b) means I can change it in my own partial `MyDatabaseEntities` with out removing it from the auto generated code, which I suspect might just get regenerated at some point. c) probably never gets called anyway.

Comment: This is trivial in OnModelCreating if you switch to code-first from an existing database.  Otherwise you'd have to edit the .edmx before creating your DbContext.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft yeah, I don't particularly want to change to code-first since that's not how our workflow has worked over the years of development we've done on this project. Switching it now seems risky for something that is ultimately only for trying some things out in development without interfering with people working on other branches.

Comment: Fair enough.  But it's not pure code-first.  "code first from an existing database" is still a database-first workflow.  But if you have any customization in your EDMX it can be a tricky transition.  So hacking the EDMX is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

So here's one, I'm sure not very efficient way to do it. But since I'm only doing this during development and not for production, maybe it'll be okay.

I thought I could set up a `DbCommandInterceptor` and use it to just rewrite the database requests to point at the table I want:

```
    public class TestingInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
    {
        public override void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
            var ctxUser = interceptionContext.DbContexts.FirstOrDefault(db => db is Dal.MyDatabaseEntities);
            if (ctxUser != null && command.CommandText.Contains($"[dbo].[{nameof(Dal.Foo)}]"))
            {
                command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace($"[dbo].[{nameof(Dal.Foo)}]", $"[dbo].[{nameof(Dal.Foo)}Dev]");
            }
            base.NonQueryExecuting(command, interceptionContext);
        }

        public override void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
            var ctxUser = interceptionContext.DbContexts.FirstOrDefault(db => db is Dal.MyDatabaseEntities);
            if (ctxUser != null && command.CommandText.Contains($"[dbo].[{nameof(Dal.Foo)}]"))
            {
                command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace($"[dbo].[{nameof(Dal.Foo)}]", $"[dbo].[{nameof(Dal.Foo)}Dev]");
            }
            base.ReaderExecuting(command, interceptionContext);
        }

        public override void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
        {
            var ctxUser = interceptionContext.DbContexts.FirstOrDefault(db => db is Dal.MyDatabaseEntities);
            if (ctxUser != null && command.CommandText.Contains($"[dbo].[{nameof(Dal.Foo)}]"))
            {
                command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace($"[dbo].[{nameof(Dal.Foo)}]", $"[dbo].[{nameof(Dal.Foo)}Dev]");
            }
            base.ScalarExecuting(command, interceptionContext);
        }
    }
```

It seems to work, but maybe there is a better way?